# Remove a suffix to a value of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame done this way:

```
 a       b         c
--------------------------------
 1     2011     mal ID9     
 2     2012     yesterday ID10 
 3     2010     misch ID10 
 4     1995     ship ID9 
 5     2008     se ID9 
 6     1998     falling ID10 
 7     2011     friend ID9 
 8     2011     use to be ID10 
       ...
```

What I want is removed the `ID9`and `ID10` suffix. The part of the string that precedes `ID9` and `ID10` has arbitrarily length so I don't know a priori.

For a reproducible example, this is my dataframe:

```
z <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                b = c(2011,2012,2010,1995,2008,1998,2011,2011),
                c = c("mal ID9", "yesterday ID10", "misch ID10", "mal ID10", "se ID9", "falling ID10", "friend ID9", "use to be ID10"))
```

and this is the result I want:

```
zz <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                b = c(2011,2012,2010,1995,2008,1998,2011,2011),
                c = c("mal", "yesterday", "misch", "mal", "se", "falling", "friend", "use to be"))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need a regular expression. You can use something like: `gsub(" ID[0-9]{1,2}$","", z$c)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
    z$c=gsub(" ID.*","",z$c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
z %>% mutate(c = gsub("\\sID\\d+$", "", c))

  a    b         c
1 1 2011       mal
2 2 2012 yesterday
3 3 2010     misch
4 4 1995       mal
5 5 2008        se
6 6 1998   falling
7 7 2011    friend
8 8 2011 use to be
```